# What is the exact manual testing in a real term project?

Tags: manual-testing

I worked as a tester in my company for 3 months. I don't know the exact process of manual testing. I worked in a small startup company. The company is developing web applications. I am only tester in my company. Nobody knows about testing.

I did not do any testing course. My company is giving a task to do manual testing of a web application.

What will I do?

How do I first start to do manual testing?

What should I learn? T

hey told me to test the application but, I am currently doing adhoc testing.

I know how to write test case.

I learn from guru99.com site.

I want to know what is the use of software testing types? There are A to Z software testing types are there.

Can you tell a brief about what is the exact manual testing process in a real term project?

Comment: @TESTeay.. Actually my question is If I got a web application for testing. What are the possibilities that I need to check ? I am checking only entering input values the check the output result.Is it the exact testing process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manual Testing** -

Cross verification of specifications on implemented application in realtime on respective platform

In the process of Manual Testing I will suggest to look at

1. Software Testing Life Cycle. See [here](http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/software-testing-life-cycle-stlc/)
2. Types of Software Testing. See [here](http://www.testingexcellence.com/types-of-software-testing-complete-list/)
3. Defect Life Cycle. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/defect_life_cycle.htm)

Comment: I know about these. I learnt from guru99.com site. But Currently I am doing random testing. What should I do? I wan to follow the other companies are doing. What shall I do?

Comment: yes, I got it. In early stage, forget about what process others are following. Try to grab knowledge and types of testing. which will help you to select appropriate type to perform testing. Which will be most fruitful to you.